# Oracle SQL*Plus: Use Substitution Variables Twice

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How do I enter a substitution variable such that it can be used multiple times throughout a SQL statement?

For example

```
SELECT '&X','&X',A       <--SEES X AS TWO DIFFERENT VARIABLES
FROM T;
```

Sees each `X` as a different variable. How can I make it such that `X` is only one variable?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a CTE or subquery so that only one reference is used, e.g. `select x, x, a from t, (select '&X' as x from dual)`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thanks, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean you are prompted twice for a value for the same variable, use 2 ampersands instead of one for a permanent substitution variable instead of a temporary substitution variable.  Here's an explanation of the difference: [What is the difference between & and &&?](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.26_and_.26.26.3F)